# Populating DataTable via SQL stored procedure yields data but only when parameter doesn't have Apostrophe/single quote

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

One of the parameters I pass to a stored procedure to populate my DT is an email address. If email address has a (') then the DT is populated with no data.

However, I did escape the (') so I know it is not likely to be the issue:

- Running the stored procedure itself with same parameter returns correct number of rows.
- Running the stored procedure from code using parameter without (') returns correct number of rows

I want to why would a presence of ('') or ('''') cause the call to not succeed, even though the the stored procedure runs? And if there is a way for me to fix this?

Things I tried:

- escaping ' before assigning value to parameter:

  ```
  if (searchTermValue.Contains('\''))
      searchTermValue = searchTermValue.Replace("'", "''''");
  ```
- escaping (') in SQL stored procedure:

  ```
  SET @searchTerm = REPLACE(@searchTerm,CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39))
  ```

I still cannot make the stored procedure return data when I call it from code & when @searchTerm has '. The call to the stored procedure is as standard as they come:

```
 {    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "rpt_EmailSearch";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FilterBy", string.Empty));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FilterType", FilterType));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@searchTerm", searchTerm));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BaseChannelID", BaseChannelID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@currentPage", currentPage));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageSize", pageSize));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortBy", sortColumn + " " + sortDirection));

            return DataFunctions.GetDataTable(cmd, DataFunctions.ConnectionString.Communicator.ToString());}
```

public static DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand cmd, string connectionStringName)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = DataFunctions.GetSqlConnection(connectionStringName))
    {
        cmd = MinDateCheck(cmd);
        cmd = MinTimeCheck(cmd);
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            dt.Load(dr);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                    
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cmd != null)
            {
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Here is the proc itself:

```
 declare
  --Payload filters
      @FilterBy varchar(50) = '',
      @FilterType varchar(50) = 'like',
      @searchTerm varchar(MAX) = '', ---THIS IS THE PARAMETER WHERE I SUPPLY 'o'test@mail.com' VALUE
      @BaseChannelID int = 92,
     --Sort filters
      @CurrentPage int = 1,
      @PageSize int = 15,
    @SortBy VARCHAR(30) = 'EmailAddress DESC',
    --Local variables
      @EmailPart varchar(MAX) = '',
      @ChannelPartOne varchar(MAX) = '',
      @ChannelPartTwo varchar(MAX) = ''    

SET @searchTerm = REPLACE(@searchTerm,CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39))


  IF @FilterType = 'equals'
  BEGIN
    SET @EmailPart = 'AND e.EmailAddress = ''' + @searchTerm + ''''
  END
  IF @FilterType = 'starts'
  BEGIN
    SET @EmailPart = 'AND e.EmailAddress like ''' + @searchTerm + '%'''
  END
  IF @FilterType = 'like'
  BEGIN
    SET @EmailPart = 'AND e.EmailAddress like ''%' + @searchTerm + '%'''
  END
  IF @FilterType = 'ends'
  BEGIN
    SET @EmailPart = 'AND e.EmailAddress like ''%' + @searchTerm + ''''
  END

  IF @BaseChannelID <> 0
  BEGIN
    SET @ChannelPartOne = 'AND bc.BaseChannelID = ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @BaseChannelID)
    SET @ChannelPartTwo = 'AND e.BaseChannelID = ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @BaseChannelID)
  END


  CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    BaseChannelName varchar(100),
    CustomerName varchar(100),
    GroupName varchar(100),
    EmailAddress varchar(100),
    SubscribeTypeCode varchar(100),
    DateCreated datetime,
    DateModified datetime
  )

  EXEC ('     
            INSERT INTO #tmp
            select 
                  bc.BaseChannelName, 
                             c.CustomerName, 
                             g.GroupName, 
                             e.EmailAddress, 
                  case when eg.SubscribeTypeCode = ''S''  then ''Subscribed'' 
                             when eg.SubscribeTypeCode = ''U'' then ''Unsubscribed'' 
                             when eg.SubscribeTypeCode = ''P'' then ''Pending'' 
                             when eg.SubscribeTypeCode = ''D'' then ''Bad Record'' 
                             when eg.SubscribeTypeCode = ''M'' then ''Master Suppressed'' else eg.SubscribeTypeCode end as ''Subscribe'', 
                  eg.CreatedOn as ''DateCreated'', eg.LastChanged as ''DateModified''
                  from
                  Emails e with (nolock)
                  join ECN5_ACCOUNTS..Customer c with (nolock) on e.CustomerID = c.CustomerID and c.IsDeleted = 0
                  join ECN5_ACCOUNTS..Basechannel bc with (nolock) on c.BaseChannelID = bc.BaseChannelID and bc.IsDeleted = 0
                  join EmailGroups eg with (nolock) on e.EmailID = eg.EmailID
                  join Groups g with (nolock) on eg.GroupID = g.GroupID and IsNull(g.MasterSupression, 0) = 0
            where
                  1=1
                  ' + @ChannelPartOne + '
                  ' + @EmailPart + '

            UNION

            select 
                  bc.BaseChannelName, '''' as ''CustomerName'', '''' as ''GroupName'', EmailAddress, ''Channel Suppressed'' as ''Subscribe'', e.CreatedDate as ''DateCreated'', e.UpdatedDate as ''DateModified''
            from
                  ChannelMasterSuppressionList e with (nolock)
                  join ECN5_ACCOUNTS..Basechannel bc with (nolock) on e.BaseChannelID = bc.BaseChannelID and bc.IsDeleted = 0
            where
                  e.IsDeleted = 0
                  ' + @ChannelPartTwo + '
                  ' + @EmailPart + '
            order by ' + @SortBy
  );

  WITH Results
  AS (SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @SortBy
    ) AS ROWNUM,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount,
    *
  FROM #tmp)
  SELECT
    *
  FROM Results
  WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN ((@CurrentPage - 1) * (@PageSize + 1)) AND (@CurrentPage * @PageSize)
  DROP TABLE #tmp
END
```

ONE MORE CORRECTION:  the version of this proc that does not run dynamic sql runs very slowly (about 6sec for Dynamic SQL, 150sec without) so I have to now revert to the version above.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would help if you showed us the SqlCommand code you are passing to this function.

Comment: `searchTermValue = searchTermValue.Replace("'", "''") `

Should be sufficient (don't try to do any more escaping), but, please use parameterized queries instead. Is your stored procedure creating SQL queries and executing them dynamically?

Comment: @willaien : I am not doing any escaping since REPLACE got added to the proc. Proc runs just fine with it: tested it as query and via calling exec in sql. 
Thanks for quick answer!

Comment: @LarsTech: 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "rpt_EmailSearch";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FilterBy", string.Empty));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FilterType", FilterType));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@searchTerm",
searchTerm));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageSize", pageSize));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortBy", sortColumn + " " + sortDirection)); 
return DataFunctions.GetDataTable(cmd, DataFunctions.ConnectionString.Communicator.ToString());

Comment: Under the tags for your post is an edit link.  Put your commented code in there.

Comment: @shivaloca, your stored procedure must be using dynamic sql. If you refactor it to not use dynamic sql then you need not worry about it at all. If you need to use dynamic order by then [see this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599492/Dynamic-ORDER-BY-with-multiple-criteria-in-T-SQL)

Comment: @Crowcoder, correct - it was using the dynamic SQL in the past (it is not now). Result remains the same: it returns data with parameter like 'test@mail.com' but not with 'o'test@mail.com' , even though the proc itself in SQL runs and returns data for both emails. 
I'll post the proc too, although I don't think it is an error in proc. May be it is something with how the connection string is generated or how SQLreader functions?

Comment: @Crowcoder, i updated the question with all relevant info, and apparently I lied - my refactored proc was too slow for clients, so I was told to go back to this.

But the issue is not the proc itself (unless i don't get how things work) - the proc gets the data with or without ('). However, data does not get populated into DT in code if searchTerm parameter has (')

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured out why it was not returning:
when command is executed the (') is **automatically** replaced with ('') so doing the Replace in the code creates the parameter that would not find a match anywhere in DB.
However, I have to do the Replace in the SQL, like below; because otherwise the dynamic SQL cannot form the proc:

```
SET @searchTerm = REPLACE(@searchTerm,CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39))
```

My mistake was that I didn't know about the automatic replace that sql command does.
Thanks everyone who answered!